# Jquery managed to break, comparing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a big amount of code for a question, but basically this was working, then i tried to tweak it and have managed to break it. Can anyone spot a problem? There may be a couple actually.

Basically, it's just me learning jquery, and I want to get a value from an input, then when a user clicks compare, it slowly produces a graph of their answer, then does the same to a preset "average" answer, and will eventually tell them the difference between their answer and the average.

```
<h2 id="compare">Compare your score with the average</h2>

<p><a href="#compare" class="run">Compare</a></p>
<div style="height:400px;position:relative;">
<div id="score" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:200px;height:2px;background-color:#01DFD7;float:left;"></div>
<div id="score2" style="position:absolute;left:220px;bottom:0px;width:200px;height:2px;background-color:#FFD;float:left;"></div>
</div>

<input id="yourValue" type="text" />

<p id="answer"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$('.run').click(function(){  
var theValue = $("#yourValue").val();
$('#score').animate({height:'theValue'}, 5000, function(){
  $('#score2').animate({height:'200px'}, 5000, function(){
      $('#answer#).html("<p>Your Answer: </p>" +  theValue);
  });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, I can't answer without 100 rep, but I found that the problem was

      $('#answer').html('<p>Your Answer: </p>' +  theValue);

needed to be:

      $('#answer').html('<b>Your Answer: </b>' +  theValue);

I have no idea why, so if anyone can shed light, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $('#answer').html('<p>Your Answer: </p>' + theValue); needed to be: $('#answer').html('<b>Your Answer: </b>' + theValue);  <- I copied and pasted that from your above answer, so you wanted it bold instead of in a paragraph? That's the only difference I see.  Please also mark the answer as accepted since that answered your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`{height:'theValue'}` - that shouldn't be in quotes.  Quotes means it's a string you actually want the value of theValue.

$('#answer#) - that's syntactically not correct.  I'm assuming you want $('#answer')

Comment: Well spotted! Made that change. I still seem to have an error somewhere, as it's not working though.

Comment: If you have FireBug on FireFox, you can view the Error Console and see if the jQuery/JS is creating an error when running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got 

"unterminated string literal
$('#answer').html('"

Comment: theValue is likely undefined as the input tag doesn't have value declared